# MEAN stack with Angular 2 - tutorials

Tags: mongodb, express, typescript, angular, mean-stack

I need to learn how to use MEAN stacks with angular 2.0 and typescript ... I know I could use JS but I am required to use typescript.

I have been going through https://angular.io/guide/quickstart guides and I am getting grips with NG2, but the issue I am facing now is how to link all the technologies together, I cannot find anywhere that shows how to interact with MongoDB via NG2+TS.

I was wondering if there any tutorials for MEAN2 stacks yet, or explain how to use mongoose with NG2.

Thanks

Comment: Angular 2 and NodeJS - The Practical Guide to MEAN Stack 2.0 from Udemy.com but I don't know if it's now free. The model is about messages, etc. but you can change the model. I created a shopping cart with login features, all CRUD operations and many other operations, session CART and not arrays. If you enjoy working with classes, I advice you to watch the video and return to stack over flow to get more answers. I am hoping my answer is ok with stack over flow to refer to Udemy
Happy coding..

Answer (score 11):

I found this http://thejackalofjavascript.com/developing-a-mean-app-with-angular-2-0/ tutorial to be very useful.

It has each step well explained from `package.json` and architecture to `Angular` services and `CSS`

Another useful one: https://www.sitepoint.com/mean-stack-angular-2-angular-cli/